# Fields from Salesforce Object not available in Marketing Cloud Import Activity. we can do using data stream, i need steps

Tags: marketing-cloud

Currently iam facing same issue. Using data stream we can achive mentioned by eliot harper. but iam unable to access that link.please provide steps how we can import using data stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedural steps for configuring Data Stream within Contact Builder (commonly referred to as 'Synchronized Data Sources') are documented on [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5).

Just remember, Salesforce Objects use a different relationship model to Marketing Cloud. Objects can have multiple relationships with other Objects, whereas Contact Builder only supports a single relationship between Objects in an Attribute Group.

When Objects are imported into Synchronized Data Extensions, field relationships are remapped using a predetermined priority based on, first, predefined standard Object relationships, then standard relationship fields (in alphabetical order), and finally, custom relationship fields (in alphabetical order). Refer to [this help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_synch_object_relationship_priority.htm&type=5) for further information.

Comment: Thank you,one small clarification. in custom object we have a field "source date" for this field data type is "long text area'. we are unable to see this field after syncing into marketing cloud. we have cross veried, filed level security also all look s good.

Comment: any suggestion why "source data" filed is not showing in marketing cloud. is this due to marketing cloud supports length only 4000 text data type? how to solve this issue